# $|x|+|y|\leq 1$ implies $|1-x|+|1-y|\geq 1$

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, inequality, triangle-inequality

Have a statement that seems true by geometric inspection but I can't seem to prove it using triangle/reverse triangle inequality.

$|x|+|y|\leq 1 \implies|1-x|+|1-y|\geq 1$

Comment: Hint: By triangle inequality, $1 = |1| \le |x| + |1 - x|$. Try proceeding by contradiction.

Comment: Another approach : Since we must have $x,y\le 1$ , you can omit the absolute-values on the right side which gives the easier inequality $2-x-y\ge 1$ equivalent to $x+y\le 1$

Comment: $|1-x|\geq 1-|x|$ and $|1-y|\geq 1-|y|$. Adding, $|1-x|+|1-y| \geq 2-(|x|+|y|) \geq 2-1=1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the triangle inequality and then the fact that $|x|+|y|\leq 1$
$$
2 = |1-x + x + 1-y + y| \leq |1-x| + |x| + |1-y| + |y|
\\
\leq 1 + |1-x| + |1-y|
$$
and your inequality follows by subtracting $1$ on both sides.